# Mutt Send Signature Hook

Tags: email, hook, mutt

I've got a send hook setup in Mutt for my signature. I usually have a few links in my sig that one customer of mine doesn't like, their email always spits it back. So to fix this I made a new signature file just for this client and setup a send hook in mutt that when it's going to this client it adds this special signature:

```
send-hook "~t @domain.com"  set signature=~/.mutt/branded.sig
set signature="~/.mutt/sig"
```

The problem now is that once I send an email to this customer then all other emails even if they go to another email address now have the new signature.

How do I tell Mutt that anything other than that email gets the regular signature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of that second "set signature" line, you want to set another send-hook for "anything other than that".
For example:

```
send-hook . set signature="~/.mutt/sig"
send-hook "~t @domain.com" set signature=~/.mutt/branded.sig
```